# Возможно ли интегрировать Яндекс.Метрику и сайт для топа посещаемых страниц?

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla, яндекс-метрика

Подскажите, возможно ли это: интегрировать сайт с Яндекс. Метрикой так, чтобы страницы брали количество посещений (каждая свои) из метрики в разрезе месяца и сортировать их по популярности (к примеру, страница с горячими за месяц постами). По сути, нужна будет выгрузка посещаемых страниц за месяц и соединение их уже с особенностями CMS. Возможно ли это? Яндекс может отдавать по запросу CRON данные?

Comment: может https://yandex.ru/dev/metrika/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> По сути, нужна будет выгрузка посещаемых страниц за месяц и
> соединение их уже с особенностями CMS. Возможно ли это? Яндекс может
> отдавать по запросу CRON данные?

Да возможно. Нужно брать [API Я.Метрики](https://yandex.ru/dev/metrika/) и писать под конкретное приложение/движок.

Answer (score 1):

**Да, можно при помощи API Яндекс Метрики, но для целей учета хитов страницы это не эффективно т.к.:**

1. Яндекс Метрика имеет ограничение на кол-во запросов;
2. Яндекс Метрика имеет ограничение на период хранение информации;
3. Многие адблокеры и некоторые версии браузеров блокируют счетчик Метрики;
4. имплементация такого получения данных значительно сложнее чем при открытии страницы приращивать счетчик хитов;

Comment: Спасибо за конструктивный комментарий. Подскажите, а как бы Вы реализовали данную задачу?

Comment: в п.4 я написал, что можно приращивать счетчикк хитов. Способ реализации будет сильно зависеть от используемой CMS и способа организации кеширования. В наиболее общем варианте это может быть реализовано размещением на страницах js скрипта, который отправлял бы запрос на конроллер счетчика при открытиии страницы. А контроллер принимал бы идентификатор страницы и учитывал бы хит